# PHP - get image from byte array

Tags: php

I am trying to create a back-end for my mobile application. I am sending an image's contents as a byte array in the HTTP request's body (output stream) I want to read this stream of bytes in the PHP script and get back an image.

Can someone please tell me how I can do that?

Thanks.

Comment: Please be more specific. What does send the byte array, how is it encoded (if it is), where is it sent (in the http request ? Then it must be encoded), etc. If you could provide an exemple it would be easier to answer.

Comment: Do you want to simply send it to a user? If that is the case just piping the bytes to output and setting the content type using header() will be sufficient. 

Or tell me what you want to do with the image in the script?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can obtain the request body by reading from [php://input](https://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php)

```
$body = file_get_contents('php://input');
```

What you do with that data is up to you. You could write the data to a file with [file_put_contents](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php). As you mentioned it is image data, you might also be able to drop the data into an [ImageMagick](http://us.php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php) object with [Imagick::readImageBlob](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.imagick-readimageblob.php). Another alternative is to use [GD](http://us.php.net/manual/en/book.image.php) and load the image with [imagecreatefromstring](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromstring.php).