# Convert binary byte array to image in PHP

Tags: php, image

I have a web service in Java which returns the requested file contents in `byte[]` (byte array) form. Sometimes these files are HTML files and sometimes they're images. There is no restriction of which file type it is. I'm looking for a way to convert this array to a valid image/string. My **working** for **text** files is below:

```
    $bytes = getArray();
    $string = implode(array_map("chr", $bytes));
    echo $string;
```

This is the output of the `echo $string;`

```
‰PNG  IHDR‘h6   pHYsÄÄ•+ OiCCPPhotoshop ICC profilexÚSgTSé=÷ÞôBKˆ€”KoR RB‹€‘&*! Jˆ!¡ÙQÁEEÈ ˆŽŽ€ŒQ,Š Øä!¢Žƒ£ˆŠÊûá{£kÖ¼÷æÍþµ×>ç¬ó³ÏÀ–H3Q5€©BàƒÇÄÆáä.@ $p³d!sý#ø~<<+"À¾xÓÀM›À0‡ÿêB™\€„Àt‘8K€@zŽB¦@F€˜&S `ËcbãP-`'æÓ€ø™{[”! ‘ eˆDh;¬ÏVŠEX0fKÄ9Ø-0IWfH°·ÀÎ²0Qˆ…){`È##x„™FòW<ñ+®ç*x™²<¹$9E[-qWW.(ÎI+6aaš@.Ây™24àóÌ ‘àƒóýxÎ®ÎÎ6Ž¶_-ê¿ÿ"bbãþåÏ«p@át~Ñþ,/³€;€mþ¢%îh^ u÷‹f²@µ éÚWópø~<ß5°j>{‘-¨]cöK'XtÀâ÷ò»oÁÔ(€hƒáÏwÿï?ýG %€fI’q^D$.TÊ³?ÇD *°AôÁ,ÀÁÜÁü`6„B$ÄÂBB d€r`)¬‚B(†Í°*`/Ô@4ÀQh†“p.ÂU¸=púažÁ(¼ AÈa!ÚˆbŠX#Ž™…ø!ÁH‹$ ÉˆQ"K‘5H1RŠT UHò=r9‡\Fº‘;È2‚ü†¼G1”²Q=ÔµC¹¨7„F¢Ðdt1š ›Ðr´=Œ6¡çÐ«hÚ>CÇ0Àè3Äl0.ÆÃB±8,  “cË±"¬«Æ°V¬»‰õcÏ±wEÀ    6wB aAHXLXNØH¨ $4Ú  7   „QÂ'"“¨K´&ºùÄb21‡XH,#Ö/{ˆCÄ7$‰C2'¹I±¤TÒÒFÒnR#é,©›4H#“ÉÚdk²9”, +È…ääÃä3ää!ò[ b@q¤øSâ(RÊjJåå4åe˜2AU£šRÝ¨¡T5ZB­¡¶R¯Q‡¨4uš9ÍƒIK¥­¢•Óhh÷i¯ètºÝ•N—ÐWÒËéGè—èôw †ƒÇˆg(›gw¯˜L¦Ó‹ÇT071ë˜ç™™oUX*¶*|‘Ê •J•&•*/T©ª¦ªÞªUóUËT©^S}®FU3Sã©   Ô–«UªPëSSg©;¨‡ªg¨oT?¤~Yý‰YÃLÃOC¤Q ±_ã¼Æ c³x,!k «†u5Ä&±ÍÙ|v*»˜ý»‹=ª©¡9C3J3W³Ró”f?ã˜qøœtN ç(§—ó~ŠÞï)â)¦4L¹1e\kª–—–X«H«Q«Gë½6®í§¦½E»YûAÇJ'\'GgÎçSÙSÝ§ §M=:õ®.ªk¥¡»Dw¿n§î˜ž¾^€žLo§Þy½çú}/ýTýmú§õGX³$ÛÎ<Å5qo</ÇÛñQC]Ã@C¥a•a—á„‘¹Ñ<£ÕFFŒiÆ\ã$ãmÆmÆ£&&!&KMêMîšRM¹¦)¦;L;LÇÍÌÍ¢ÍÖ™5›=1×2ç›ç›×›ß·`ZxZ,¶¨¶¸eI²äZ¦Yî¶¼n…Z9Y¥XUZ]³F­­%Ö»­»§§¹N“N«žÖgÃ°ñ¶É¶©·°åØÛ®¶m¶}agbg·Å®Ãî“½“}º}ý= ‡Ù«Z~s´r:V:ÞšÎœî?}Åô–é/gXÏÏØ3ã¶Ë)ÄiS›ÓGgg¹sƒóˆ‹‰K‚Ë.—>.›ÆÝÈ½äJtõq]ázÒõ›³›Âí¨Û¯î6îiî‡ÜŸÌ4Ÿ)žY3sÐÃÈCàQåÑ?Ÿ•0kß¬~OCOgµç#/c/‘W­×°·¥wª÷aï>ö>rŸã>ã<7Þ2ÞY_Ì7À·È·ËOÃož_…ßC#ÿdÿzÿÑ§€%g‰A[ûøz|!¿Ž?:Ûeö²ÙíAŒ ¹AA‚­‚åÁ­!hÈì­!÷ç˜Î‘Îi…P~èÖÐaæa‹Ã~'…‡…W†?ŽpˆXÑ1—5wÑÜCsßDúD–DÞ›g1O9¯-J5*>ª.j<Ú7º4º?Æ.fYÌÕXXIlK9.*®6nl¾ßüíó‡ââã{˜/È]py¡ÎÂô…§©.,:–@LˆN8”ðA*¨Œ%òw%Ž yÂÂg"/Ñ6ÑˆØC\*NòH*Mz’ì‘¼5y$Å3¥,å¹„'©¼L LÝ›:žšv m2=:½1ƒ’‘qBª!M“¶gêgæfvË¬e…²þÅn‹·/•Ék³¬Y- ¶B¦èTZ(×*²geWf¿Í‰Ê9–«ž+ÍíÌ³ÊÛ7œïŸÿíÂá’¶¥†KW-Xæ½¬j9²‰Š®Û—Ø(Üxå‡oÊ¿™Ü”´©«Ä¹dÏfÒféæÞ-ž[–ª—æ—n ÙÚ´ ßV´íõöEÛ/—Í(Û»ƒ¶C¹£¿<¸¼e§ÉÎÍ;?T¤TôTúT6îÒÝµa×ønÑî{¼ö4ìÕÛ[¼÷ý>É¾ÛUUMÕfÕeûIû³÷?®‰ªéø–ûm]­NmqíÇÒý#¶×¹ÔÕÒ=TRÖ+ëGÇ¾þïw- 6 UœÆâ#pDyäé÷  ß÷ :ÚvŒ{¬áÓvg/jBšòšF›Sšû[b[ºOÌ>ÑÖêÞzüGÛœ499â?rýéü§CÏdÏ&žþ¢þË®/~øÕë×ÎÑ˜Ñ¡—ò—“¿m|¥ýêÀë¯ÛÆÂÆ¾Éx31^ôVûíÁwÜwï£ßOä| (ÿhù±õSÐ§û“““ÿ˜óüc3-Û cHRMz%€ƒùÿ€éu0ê`:˜o’_ÅFìIDATxÚÁIoUàyËŒ§3žÅN°/Ávš BÛiQ¥J=ô€¢^*nHpAøHÜøœzABÀ$$$TRDQ$$C’62‰—8Nâ‰ñÄÛxÞìoæñ} qðûÁ^Ã%¤T]ÆXl5O¿ÿqÇ¸üo:J²ª)ÊÖÃ{Ÿ}úØš9öÌ~çÞ›èñö»\ˆ)atð²ùõ“Ÿ..NgF£B(§•ÆÑIä;•bŽã\Ô¥J)¿V)®ä–êõÃÑ³m‹±øÕB‡ÜÀ8ŸL®ž=¯Ó(,&–…çvE>ÇM’ÎIÏuü‚þÉ£íoßùcw÷×?ŸwÍQ»Ý1Œa±£1ÃÖtÑ†>ä(cqÓ·>úà=”’²²tÿöíF·óÍoÏ\×‰CŸ"Œ9  0f²`2ªZ-¬ü°³;š«ù…ÀÎ¦¶šÉ6»ƒ¬¦jXÂæpŒH‰Â5m]¿þBVÿíµùî[FKMK«Çýé|k£¦¨RL#<™â0E{£VãÓZVOï7FSëã÷·oÞ¸ùùW_Ôª¥‡÷ïò¼à{!øùÉ—–íÙsWH+¼ÏOÏªÅ%âÞÜ*è‹Š¾Ð1zâ¢¬æ5Ïá¤xàêºf†Oÿn•u­Z)ëZ˜Ñ:³ÑÑÑêu>;íÞÜñÜñXÂù>Ùk­îåúÝŒ9¾šM“±9JÙ Äñt"h®XÂ­”Pry5kœÛÍ¾- T+}bõGãõJe.ºÔóFn¸ ‹›¯—=xwÉ^s6&6Ç(@xAí•l»×{ZßgIÐä¯“þÍ·6’„
```

But I have no idea how to do this for image files. I could somehow write this array to a file and load the image but my project doesn't allow me to do that. I have to do this on the fly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If all you want to do is show the image to the user, you simply need to serve the right content header with the response:

```
if      (substr($string, 0, 4) == "\x89PNG")  header('Content-Type: image/png');
else if (substr($string, 0, 2) == "\xFF\xD8") header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
else if (substr($string, 0, 4) == "GIF8")     header('Content-Type: image/gif');

echo $string;
```

An image is really just a blob of data (like the 'string' you have) plus an indication that it's an image (in HTTP, that would be the MIME header). Since you already have the blob, all you need is the header to make the browser interpret it as an image.

Comment: I think I'm on the right track. When I add the content type manually (depending on the URL), it works. But the if/else code above is not recognizing the content correctly. This is the output for PNG: `‰PNG` (I mean `echo substr($string, 0, 4);`)

Comment: Awesome. Working like a charm. How about the BMP and TIFF images? Should I worry about them?

Comment: Depends, do you ever come across those? If yes, then yes you should worry about them.

Answer (score 1):

You mean like in the examples shown here: http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromstring.php

```
$data = 'iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABwAAAASCAMAAAB/2U7WAAAABl'
       . 'BMVEUAAAD///+l2Z/dAAAASUlEQVR4XqWQUQoAIAxC2/0vXZDr'
       . 'EX4IJTRkb7lobNUStXsB0jIXIAMSsQnWlsV+wULF4Avk9fLq2r'
       . '8a5HSE35Q3eO2XP1A1wQkZSgETvDtKdQAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==';
$data = base64_decode($data);

$im = imagecreatefromstring($data);
if ($im !== false) {
    header('Content-Type: image/png');
    imagepng($im);
    imagedestroy($im);
}
else {
    echo 'An error occurred.';
}
```

Comment: Using the same `$string` in the code above, it says: imagecreatefromstring(): Empty string or invalid image

Comment: When you echo $string, what does it show? Can you add that to your question, so that I have some data to work with?

Comment: Try it with the base64_decode(), also try base64_encode() on the string, and also try just using the String variable without any encode/decode. I cant tell what the original byte array contains so Im not sure which function will work.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$body = file_get_contents('php://input');
```

and also refer [PHP - get image from byte array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1170006/php-get-image-from-byte-array)

Comment: Could you tell me how to use it? Does it redirect output? Should I echo the array or something?!

Comment: What you do with that data is up to you. You could write the data to a file with file_put_contents. As you mentioned it is image data, you might also be able to drop the data into an ImageMagick object with Imagick::readImageBlob. Another alternative is to use GD and load the image with imagecreatefromstring.

Comment: OK. I could read the comment. The solution is suggesting to read the stream from request. I HAVE the binary data. I just don't know how to convert it to image.

Answer (score 0):

Using below code we can create image from byte array code.

```
$userId             = $userid;
    $encoded_image      = $imgurl;
    $upload_path        = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/projectName/uploads/";
    $LoginUserDetails   = $this->getUserDetails($userId);
    if ($LoginUserDetails->profile_image != "") {
        $dbimgname      = $LoginUserDetails->profile_image;
        unlink($upload_path .$dbimgname);
        unlink($upload_path . 'thumb_img/' . $dbimgname);
    }
    $decoded_image = base64_decode($encoded_image);
    $imgname       = md5(uniqid()) . ".png";
    file_put_contents($upload_path . $imgname, $decoded_image);

    $thumbnail      = $upload_path . "thumb_img/" . $imgname; // Set the thumbnail name
    $actual         = $upload_path . $imgname; // Set the actual image name
    // Get new sizes

    $upload_image = $upload_path.$imgname;
    //  print_r($actual); print_r($thumbnail); print_r($upload_image); die;
    list($width, $height) = getimagesize($upload_image);
    $newwidth  = 196; // This can be a set value or a percentage of original size ($width)
    $newheight = 196; // This can be a set value or a percentage of original size ($height)
    // Load the images
    $thumb     = imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth, $newheight);
    $source    = imagecreatefrompng($upload_image);
    //print_r($upload_image); print_r($source); die;
    imagecopyresized($thumb, $source, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newwidth, $newheight, $width, $height); // Resize the $thumb image.
    imagepng($thumb, $thumbnail, 100); // Save the new file to the location specified by $thumbnail

    return $imgname;
```