# php convert byte array to image

Tags: php, image, byte, converters

I have an array, below is part of it (it is over 3000 items) and I need to convert the byte data to an image (jpg) any ideas how I do this?

Thanks.

```
[0] => 255
    [1] => 216
    [2] => 255
    [3] => 224
    [4] => 0
    [5] => 16
    [6] => 74
    [7] => 70
    [8] => 73
    [9] => 70
    [10] => 0
    [11] => 1
    [12] => 1
    [13] => 1
    [14] => 0
    [15] => 96
    [16] => 0
    [17] => 96
    [18] => 0
    [19] => 0
    [20] => 255
```

Comment: what was the process by which you received the array in your question?

Comment: Is the array just the numerical representation of the image data, i.e. if I encounter 216, does it mean that the byte should have the value 216?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert binary byte array to image in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15222114/convert-binary-byte-array-to-image-in-php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be working

```
$fp = fopen("image.jpg", "wb");

$len = count($array);

for ($i = 0; $i < $len; $i++) {
    $data = pack("C*",$array[$i]);
    fwrite($fp, $data);
}
fclose($fp);
```

adopted from [here](http://blog-en.openalfa.com/how-to-work-with-binary-data-in-php)